# Hexadecimal to bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, hex, byte

I am using a AES program and the output in encrypted format is a bytearray. From one string I am given

```
e37c1a5132a9a121d4fbb98ba42a684
```

however the hex array is supposed to be

```
e3 7c 1a 51 32 a9 a1 21 d4 fb b9 8b 0a 42 a6 84
```

The 4th to last term is 0a but in the concatenated string is showing up as just a plain a. How can I detect this?

In the attached link below I am trying to go from the first generated link to a byte array however when i am missing the 0 in the 0a, the string crashes.

http://laurentcharignon.com/blog/?p=37

Comment: how are you making the string(the one that is missing the 0(?

Comment: I'm no expert but can you send another couple of bytes as CRC check and discard the faulty ones?

Comment: For some reason, I guess when I ran it, this line didnt execute, but under encryption this line safeguards it:
if ((data[i]&0xFF)<16)
   str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the loop, the`hex()`function result doesn't include leading zeros after the`'0x'`prefix for values less that 16, so`hex(10)`is`'0xa'`and`hex(10)[2:]`is`'a'`(the call to`str()`is unnecessary). So instead of:

```
result = ""
for char in ciph:
    result += str((hex(ord(char))))[2:]
```

You could avoid using`hex()`with something like this:

```
result = ""
for char in ciph:
    result += '%02x' % ord(char)
```

A slightly more concise way to do the same thing would be with a generator expression:

```
result = ''.join('%02x' % ord(char) for char in ciph)
```

Spaces could be added between each 2-byte hex value with the following slightly different expression to make the result more readable:

```
       ' '.join('%02x' % ord(char) for char in ciph)
```

Answer (score 2):

This kind of missing information is not recoverable. You have to fix the place that generates this broken string. Another valid source string for producing your string above would be:

```
e3 7c 1a 51 32 a9 a1 21 d4 fb b9 8b a4 02 a6 84
```

Here the 0 is inserted one place later. On a technical level it is not possible to infer which of these source strings was used to produce the above hex representation with zeros dropped.